# Count occurrences around a genomic region given in a data frame

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I need to count mutations in the genome that occur at certain spots or rather ranges. The mutations have a genomic position (chromosome and basepair, e.g. Chr1, 10658324). The range or spot, respectively, is defined as 10000 basepairs up- and downstream (+-) of a given position in the genome. Both, positions of mutations and position of "spots" are stored in data frames.

Example:

```
set.seed(1)

Chr <- 1
Pos <- as.integer(runif(5000 , 0, 1e8))
mutations <- data.frame(Pos, Chr)

Chr <- 1
Pos <- as.integer(runif(50 , 0, 1e8))
spots <- data.frame(Pos, Chr)
```

So the question I am asking is: How many mutations are present +-10k basepairs around the positions given in "spots". (e.g. if the spot is 100k, the range would be 90k-110k)
The real data would of course contain all 24 chromosomes, but for the sake of simplicity we can focus on one chromosome for now.
The final data should contain the "spot" and the number of mutations in it's vicinity, ideally in a data frame or matrix.

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions or help!

---

Here's a first attempt, but I am pretty shure there is a way more elegant way of doing it.

```
w <- 10000  #setting range to 10k basepairs
loop <- spots$Pos  #creating vector of positions to loop through
out <- data.frame(0,0)
colnames(out) <- c("Pos", "Count")

for (l in loop) {
  temp <- nrow(filter(mutations, Pos>=l-w, Pos<=l+w))
  temp2 <- cbind(l,temp)
  colnames(temp2) <- c("Pos", "Count")
  out <- rbind(out, temp2)
}
 out <- out[-1,]
```

Comment: this is very specific , if you want to get help from R community, then it is better you provide an input and an expected output example , then people will understand what you are looking for

Comment: Why are you using pseudo-random numbers from a continuous distribution to simulate what is occurring on a discrete (integer) distribution? You should post an example where you are capable of giving the "correct" answer.

Comment: Take a lookt at the Genomic Ranges that will provide you with usefull set operations: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am realtively new to R and don't know how to provide the actual data. The above sample was only ment to supply a rough idea of what the data looks like. Also, I don't know the "correct" answer but giving the example above the output should look somewhat like this: `nrow(filter(mutations, Pos>=9.8e5 , Pos<= 1e6))`
Only that it should loop through the mutation df and store the number of mutation in a df2. In this case the answer is 3. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using data.table foverlaps, then aggregate:

```
library(data.table)
#set the flank
myFlank <- 100000

#convert to ranges with flank
spotsRange <- data.table(
  chr = spots$Chr,
  start = spots$Pos - myFlank,
  end = spots$Pos + myFlank,
  posSpot = spots$Pos,
  key = c("chr", "start", "end"))

#convert to ranges start end same as pos
mutationsRange <- data.table(
  chr = mutations$Chr,
  start = mutations$Pos,
  end = mutations$Pos,
  key = c("chr", "start", "end"))

#merge by overlap
res <- foverlaps(mutationsRange, spotsRange, nomatch = 0)

#count mutations
resCnt <- data.frame(table(res$posSpot))
colnames(resCnt) <- c("Pos", "MutationCount")
merge(spots, resCnt, by = "Pos")
#         Pos Chr MutationCount
# 1   3439618   1            10
# 2   3549952   1            15
# 3   4375314   1            11
# 4   7337370   1            13
# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with bed manipulations in R, so I'm going propose an answer with bedtools and someone here can try to convert to GRanges or other R bioinformatics library.

Essentially, you have two bed files, one with your spots and other with your mutations (I'm assuming a 1bp coordinate for each in the latter). In this case, you'd use `closestBed` to get the closest spot and the distance in bp of each mutation and then filter those that are 10KB from the spots. The code in a UNIX environment would look something like this:

```
# Assuming 4-column file structure (chr start end name)
closestBed -d -a mutations.bed -b spots.bed | awk '$9 <= 10000 {print}'
```

Where column 9 (`$9`) will be the distance in bp from the closest spot. Depending on how more specific you want to be, you can check the manual page at http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/closest.html. I'm pretty sure there's at least one bedtools-like package in R. If the functionality is similar, you can apply this exact same solution.

Hope that helps!